# Looping thru nested array, and also being able to search/filter it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

today I am coming here to ask for some help on a problem that I've ran into.

So I'm making a dashboard, where it loops thru criminal charges.

So i have it set up in a database with structure of the table looking like this

```
category charges
```

So it holds the category, and also the specific charges that belong to that category.

So what I am trying to do is, loop thru the categories, and inside of the category loop also loop thru the charges for that category.

I know I can do this by just mapping thru each category, and then mapping charges inside of the first map. But then we run into a problem. And that problem is that how do I filter that? For example I want to filter by "title" key in charges for each category, so if I search it will filter out and show only the charges that match in any category.

This is the structure of my data: (that's whats inside of the chargesData state)

```
0: {category: "Infractions", charges: Array(30), color: "#417011", id: 1}
1: {category: "Misdemeanors", charges: Array(60), color: "#7e5800", id: 2}
2: {category: "Felonies", charges: Array(99), color: "#7e2100", id: 3}
```

Charges structure:

```
0: {fine: "500", months: "0", points: "0", title: "Failure to stop at Red Light"}
1: {fine: "500", months: "0", points: "0", title: "Failure to stop at Stop Sign"}
```

My current code, as I've explained it in the post:

```
<div className="outer-content">
    {chargesData && chargesData.length > 0 ? (
        chargesData.map((cat) => (
            <div className="inner-content">
                <Typography style={{ color: '#fff', wordBreak: 'break-word' }} variant="h6" gutterBottom>{cat.category}</Typography>
                <div className="inner-content-body" style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', flex: '0', overflowY: 'unset', paddingLeft: '1.5%' }}>
                    {cat.charges && cat.charges.length > 0 ? (
                        cat.charges.map((charge) => (
                            <Typography style={{ color: '#fff', wordBreak: 'break-word', textAlign: 'center' }} variant="body1" gutterBottom>{charge.title}</Typography>
                            <Typography style={{ color: '#fff', wordBreak: 'break-word', textAlign: 'center' }} variant="body2" gutterBottom>{charge.months !== undefined ? charge.months : '0'} months</Typography>
                            <Typography style={{ color: '#fff', wordBreak: 'break-word', textAlign: 'center' }} variant="body2" gutterBottom>{charge.fine !== undefined ? charge.fine : '$0.0'}</Typography>
                            <Typography style={{ color: '#fff', wordBreak: 'break-word', textAlign: 'center' }} variant="body2" gutterBottom>{charge.points !== undefined ? charge.points : '0'} point(s)</Typography>
                            ))
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        ))
    ) : (
    <></>
)}
</div>
```

Hopefully someone has the answer, thanks again for reading.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep you filter string on state

```
const [chargeTitleSearch, setChargeTitleSearch] = useState("");
```

Then you can create the filter function

```
const filterFn = t => !chargeTitleSearch || t.match(chargeTitleSearch); // or whatever
```

Then use the filter

```
cat.charges.filter(c => filterFn(c.title)).map(...);
```

If you want to omit any categories that have no data after filtering:

```
// Make a new list with the charges in each category filtered out
const filterChargeData = chargesData.map(c => {
  return { ...c, charges: c.charges.filter(cc => filterFn(cc.title))};
});

// Filter the categories based on whether or not they contain any charges.
const nonEmptyCategories = filterChargeData.filter(c => c.charges.length);
```

Comment: Will try this, and let you know.

Comment: Okay, having an error TypeError: e.match is not a function

Comment: Ok, changed it to t.title.match(chargeTitleSearch), And it loads. No errors. But when I search nothing comes up/matches. I also tried converting chargeTitleSearch into a string aswell as making that lowercase. Also did it to the t.title aswell. But no luck there either.

Comment: You will have to update your question with the searching code.

Comment: it's the answer on the question. that's what i used. and his answer did not work!

Comment: The only reason I ask is because it works when I use filterFn

Comment: Okay, I changed the t.match to t.startsWith.  Worked better for my needs. Anyways how would you  also make it so if there is no matches in the other categories for example Infractions it hides that category? Would that be in the scope of possibility?

Comment: Of course, anything is possible. You control the data. I updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: Okay, you don't explain to how to integrate the added on part? Like should I replace that with the other one you put in ur answer? Lmk

Comment: You said you wanted to only use non-empty categories, so use nonEmptyCategories instead of chargesData. Btw it's pretty useless to copypaste my untested code into your project, read the comments to try and understand what's going on.

Comment: Okay, will do. I've always found it hard with this kind of stuff. But you just gotta learn it. Thanks for all the help. Will mark your answer as the solution now.